# How can I add Processing to the Unity launcher?

Tags: launcher, software-installation

[Processing](http://www.processing.org/) is an open-source language and environment for learning the fundamentals of electronic art and computer programming.

Its Linux download package includes a file called `processing` that, when run, opens the main Processing IDE.

[image: Processing IDE screenshot]

How can I add this program to the Unity launcher in Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great! There's an error where it says: [Desktop Entry] Version=2.1 Name=Processing ... It should be: [Desktop Entry] Version=2.1 Name=Processing ... I tried editing but it's a less than 10 character and it doesn't allow me to.

Answer (score 12):

### Install Processing

Once you have downloaded Processing it first needs to be unpacked.

```
tar zxvf processing-2.1-linux64.tgz
```

The `processing` file then needs to be copied to `/usr/bin`

```
cd processing-2.1
sudo mv processing /usr/bin/
```

The rest of the files then need to be copied to the `/opt` directory.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/processing
sudo cp -r processing-2.1/* /opt/processing/
```

The tldp website provides a great explanation of why to install to `/opt`

> This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages
>   that are not part of the default installation. For example,
>   StarOffice, Kylix, Netscape Communicator and WordPerfect packages are
>   normally found here. To comply with the FSSTND, all third party
>   applications should be installed in this directory. Any package to be
>   installed here must locate its static files (ie. extra fonts, clipart,
>   database files) must locate its static files in a separate
>   /opt/'package' or /opt/'provider' directory tree (similar to the way
>   in which Windows will install new software to its own directory tree
>   C:\Windows\Progam Files\"Program Name"), where 'package' is a name
>   that describes the software package and 'provider' is the provider's
>   LANANA registered name.
>
> Although most distributions neglect to create the directories
>   /opt/bin, /opt/doc, /opt/include, /opt/info, /opt/lib, and /opt/man
>   they are reserved for local system administrator use. Packages may
>   provide "front-end" files intended to be placed in (by linking or
>   copying) these reserved directories by the system administrator, but
>   must function normally in the absence of these reserved directories.
>   Programs to be invoked by users are located in the directory
>   /opt/'package'/bin. If the package includes UNIX manual pages, they
>   are located in /opt/'package'/man and the same substructure as
>   /usr/share/man must be used. Package files that are variable must be
>   installed in /var/opt. Host-specific configuration files are installed
>   in /etc/opt.
>   Interpret this as you wish, but to my understanding you do this if you want to run a self-contained package i.e. one that contains all that is needed within the download itself.

Next it needs to be linked to java

```
cd /opt/processing 
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun java
```

And finally to create a link

```
sudo sed -i 's/APPDIR=`readlink -f "$0"`//'g /usr/bin/processing
sudo sed -i 's/`dirname "$APPDIR"`/\/opt\/processing/'g /usr/bin/processing
```

### Create Unity launcher

With Processing now "installed" the launcher can now be made. The Ubuntu website provides a [good tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) of this, which is summarised below. First, create the launcher

```
sudo touch /usr/share/applications/processing.desktop
```

And then open it for editing

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/processing.desktop
```

With the file now open fill it with the following information and save.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.1 
Name=Processing 
Comment=graphics and animation language 
Exec=processing
Icon=/opt/processing/lib/icons/pde-256.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Video;Graphics;
```

With that now saved you should be able to find Processing in the Unity Dash

[image: Processing in Unity Dash]

Upgrading will require you to just copy over the files in /opt/processing with the new ones, though do check that the directory and file structure is the same as before.

### Associate .pde files with Processing

Finally, to associate .pde files with Processing - so double-clicking a .pde launches Processing - you need create a new MIME type and associate Processing with that type.

The GNOME dev center [provides an explanation](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/mime.html.en) of how to create a new MIME type. First, create the new MIME type

```
sudo touch /usr/share/mime/packages/processing.xml
```

Then open it for editing

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/mime/packages/processing.xml
```

Put the following data in that file and then save it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="text/x-processing">
        <comment>Proecssing source code</comment>
        <sub-class-of type="text/x-csrc"/>
        <glob pattern="*.pde"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Update the MIME database

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Finally, associate the new MIME type with Processing. The default applications list is stored in a file called `defaults.list`

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Add `text/x-processing=processing.desktop` somewhere in that file.

Now, when you double-click a .pde file it'll open the file Processing.

Comment: I was able to create a unity launcher file successfully, but when I click on the icon, nothing happens. I'm forced to run it using ./processing

Comment: I followed the steps carefully and didn't notice anything wrong. I've also changed the version no. wherever needed.

Comment: Probably you want to link to `default-java` instead of `java-6-sun`.

Comment: Thanks. Everything is working. But now the `pde` file has icon as `txt` file. How to have the icon with blue C back.

Comment: thank you. worked perfectly with `ubuntu 16`, `processing-3.2.3` and `Java 8`.